# How to adjust text width in R?

Tags: r, text, width

Is there a function that does this?

input:

```
text <- "I have a little dog"
```

desired output:

```
some_function(text, max_width = 8)

#output: "I have a\nlittle dog"

some_function(text, max_width = 15)
  
#output: "I have a little\ndog"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stringr::str_wrap` does this :

```
text <- "I have a little dog"
stringr::str_wrap(text, 15)
#[1] "I have a little\ndog"
```

Output may vary in certain cases because of the underlying algorithm it uses.

```
stringr::str_wrap(text, 8)
[1] "I have\na little\ndog"
```